# PHP Symfony curl post data not found

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I'm trying to send Post data from a symfony project to another Symfony project (used as API). But the data doesn't seem to follow the request..

The problem seem to come from the cURL post data needing to be repost after the Url change. Because if I remove the "curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);", the response is an html page trying to refresh the same page asked.

I use to get "args not found" according to the following code..

Controller calling (Project A)

```
public function onlineHandlerAction(Request $req, $name, $surname)
{

    $url = $this->getParameter("api"). "avis/find";

    $args = array(
        "name" => "qsdqsdqsd",
        "surname" => $surname,
        "birthdate" => $defunt->getBirthDate()->getTimestamp()
    );

    $apiRes = $kgns->CallAPI('POST', $url, $args);

    var_dump($apiRes);

    return $this->render('**:online-handler.html.twig', array(
        'res' => $apiRes
    ));                                             

}
```

call api function that I found on the web and edit for my need.
(tool of Project A)

```
public function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{

    $curl = curl_init();

  switch ($method)
  {
      case "POST":
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

          if ($data)
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
          break;
      case "PUT":
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
          break;
      default:
          if ($data)
              $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
  }

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);    
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 1);

  $result = curl_exec($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  return $result;

}
```

api function (Project B)

```
public function avisFindAction(Request $req)
{


  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $args = $req->request->all();

  $argsFound = false;


  if(null !== $args && count($args) > 0):

    $argsFound = true;

    foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
      if($key=='birthdate') $args[$key] = new \DateTime($value);
      else $args[$key] = $value;
    }

    $avis = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Avis')
                  ->findOneBy($args);

    if($avis):

      $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());               
      $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
      $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
      $avisJSON = $serializer->serialize($avis, 'json');

      $response = new Response($avisJSON);
      $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return $response;

    else:

      $response = ["error"=>"avis not found"];

    endif;

  else:

    $response = ["error"=>"args not found"];

  endif;

  return new JsonResponse(['test'=>'test', 'argsFound'=>$argsFound]);

}
```

Comment: Do the API that you are calling is under authentification ? The redirect could be redirect to login page

Comment: @Mcsky thank for reply but no is not. It redirect to same page. I tried with another route, and no redirection. I don't why this route has the redirect..

Comment: The best information you could get is in the logs of the server B (for that you have to change your monolog configuration to debug level on this server). If you have the project B in a dev environment try it on your local machine before a prod/preprod env. You should see your call from project A to B in the log and the reason of the redirect. For me two possible reasons, a security config or a listener returning a RedirectResponse. Let me know when you have this information :)

Comment: @Mcsky I fixe this problem by re-writing my route in the project B. ( but write it in the realy way ) but the error wasn't there anymore. Didn't understand but as it running... Thank you for your help!

Comment: That is cool :) Just be sure that your route is not open without authentification in the web for obvious security reasons